# Copy value in text format to different cells based on pattern matching

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is my data starting from column A from row-1

[image]

Question 1) Need formula for counting rows which has pattern matching for first 3 characters as 000,010,020,999 ??

In the above example it will be 5 and these 5 rows are header of a file; that means I have only 11 rows of data in which first 3 characters are 030

Question 2) Need macro to copy the above data of column A to other column's G,H,I,J,K,L,M and N as per below rule starting from row 2 to row 12

```
COLUMN B ===> start="4" length="5" where Record Type = 000  
COLUMN C ===> start="20" length="8" format="MMddyyyy" where Record Type = 000  
COLUMN D ===> start="28" length="3" where Record Type = 000  
COLUMN E ===> start="4" length="25" where Record Type = 010  
COLUMN F ===> start="60" length="20" where Record Type = 010  
COLUMN G ===> start="12" length="15" where Record Type = 020  
COLUMN H ===> start="65" length="1" where Record Type = 020  
COLUMN I ===> start="66" length="25" where Record Type = 020  
COLUMN J ===> start="4" length="30" where Record Type = 030   
COLUMN K ===> start="34" length="30" where Record Type = 030  
COLUMN L ===> start="64" length="30" where Record Type = 030  
COLUMN M ===> start="94" length="30" where Record Type = 030  
COLUMN N ===> start="154" length="23" where Record Type = 030
```

o/p for the above rules will be only for 11 rows and it will be as below.

[image]

I have created a macro but the loop for the vaules in respective columns is giving me more output then the no of rows i.e. 11

I think some issue in the loop.

```
Macro -  

 Sub Macro_CopyData()

 'clear contents before every run

 Range("B1:X10000").Select
 Selection.ClearContents

 ' converting all fields to text

 Range("B1:X100000").NumberFormat = "@"

Dim myrange, cell As Range

 Dim i, j, k, l As Integer, count, count2 As Integer, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, data3,   ColumnD, ColumnE, ColumnF, ColumnG, ColumnH, ColumnI, ColumnI, ColumnK, ColumnL, ColumnM  As Variant

'counting number of rows in column A

count = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
MsgBox count
Set myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

  ' assigning column names

Cells(1, 2).Value = "ColumnA"
Cells(1, 3).Value = "ColumnB"
Cells(1, 4).Value = "ColumnC"
Cells(1, 5).Value = "ColumnD"
Cells(1, 6).Value = "ColumnE"
Cells(1, 7).Value = "ColumnF"
Cells(1, 8).Value = "ColumnG"
Cells(1, 9).Value = "ColumnH"
Cells(1, 10).Value = "ColumnI"
Cells(1, 11).Value = "ColumnJ"
Cells(1, 12).Value = "ColumnK"
Cells(1, 13).Value = "ColumnL"
Cells(1, 14).Value = "ColumnM"

  For Each cell In myrange
  ' assigning values to the variables
    ColumnA = Mid(cell.Value, 4, 5)
    ColumnB = Mid(cell.Value, 20, 8)
    ColumnC = Mid(cell.Value, 28, 3)
    ColumnD = Mid(cell.Value, 4, 25)
    ColumnE = Mid(cell.Value, 60, 20)
    ColumnF = Mid(cell.Value, 12, 15)
    ColumnG = Mid(cell.Value, 65, 1)
    ColumnH = Mid(cell.Value, 66, 25)
    ColumnI = Mid(cell.Value, 4, 30)
    ColumnJ = Mid(cell.Value, 34, 30)
    ColumnK = Mid(cell.Value, 64, 30)
    ColumnL = Mid(cell.Value, 94, 30)
    ColumnM = Mid(cell.Value, 154, 23)

  For i = 1 To count - 4
  If Left(cell.Value, 3) = "000" Then

   cell.Offset(i, 1).Value = ColumnA
   cell.Offset(i, 2).Value = ColumnB
   cell.Offset(i, 3).Value = ColumnC

   End If
    Next i


  For j = 0 To count - 5
  If Left(cell.Value, 3) = "010" Then
  cell.Offset(j, 4).Value = ColumnD
  cell.Offset(j, 5).Value = ColumnE

   End If
  Next j



  For k = -1 To count - 1

  If Left(cell.Value, 3) = "020" Then
  cell.Offset(k, 6).Value = ColumnF
  cell.Offset(k, 7).Value = ColumnG
  cell.Offset(k, 8).Value = ColumnH
 End If
 Next k


 For l = -2 To count

  If Left(cell.Value, 3) = "030" Then
   cell.Offset(l, 9).Value = ColumnI
   cell.Offset(l, 10).Value = ColumnJ
   cell.Offset(l, 11).Value = ColumnK
   cell.Offset(l, 12).Value = ColumnL
   cell.Offset(l, 13).Value = ColumnM

  End If
  Next l

  Next cell


  End Sub
```

Comment: does anybody have any more questions....let me know if there are any....need urgent help on this...Thanks

Comment: @simoco can you please help me

Comment: It's not clear from your question what the purpose of the inner loops (i,j,k,l) is.

Comment: @TimWilliams the inner loop is used to copy the value assigned to variables columnB,C,D etc into the required cells..what we need is that value J9 should be present in cells B2:B12 (11 times as per the total number of rows)...so i have used the loop "i" for value in columnA,columnB,coulumnC

Comment: @TimWilliams may be my macro is not good and a complicated one as this is my first time on macro.....could you help to get an optimized the macro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** try this - I think it's close to what you're trying to do.

```
Sub Macro_CopyData()

    Dim sht As Worksheet, cell As Range, myRange As Range
    Dim arrHeaders, pre, rw As Range
    Dim A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    With sht.Range("B1:X10000")
        .ClearContents
        .NumberFormat = "@"
    End With

    arrHeaders = Array("ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC", "ColumnD", _
                       "ColumnE", "ColumnF", "ColumnG", "ColumnH", _
                       "ColumnI", "ColumnJ", "ColumnK", "ColumnL", _
                       "ColumnM")
    'place headers on sheet
    sht.Cells(1, 2).Resize(1, UBound(arrHeaders) + 1).Value = arrHeaders

    Set myRange = sht.Range(sht.Cells(2, 1), _
                      sht.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In myRange.Cells

        Set rw = cell.EntireRow
        pre = Left(cell.Value, 3)

        Select Case pre

            Case "000"
                A = Mid(cell.Value, 4, 5)
                B = Mid(cell.Value, 20, 8)
                C = Mid(cell.Value, 28, 3)

            Case "010"
                D = Mid(cell.Value, 4, 5)
                E = Mid(cell.Value, 20, 8)

            Case "020"
                F = Mid(cell.Value, 12, 15)
                G = Mid(cell.Value, 65, 1)
                H = Mid(cell.Value, 66, 25)

            Case "030"
                rw.Cells(2).Value = A
                rw.Cells(3).Value = B
                rw.Cells(4).Value = C
                rw.Cells(5).Value = D
                rw.Cells(6).Value = E
                rw.Cells(7).Value = F
                rw.Cells(8).Value = G
                rw.Cells(9).Value = H
                rw.Cells(10).Value = Mid(cell.Value, 4, 30)
                rw.Cells(11).Value = Mid(cell.Value, 34, 30)
                rw.Cells(12).Value = Mid(cell.Value, 64, 30)
                rw.Cells(13).Value = Mid(cell.Value, 94, 30)
                rw.Cells(14).Value = Mid(cell.Value, 154, 23)

         End Select

    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for ur effort, we are not getting expected result,may be bcoz the quest is not self explanatory, i will re-iterate my question in my next comment.

Comment: i have edited my question and uploaded the image....the first image of column A is my data from a text file....and the second image is the required o/p from column B to column N which we need after running macro......and the rules are mentioned in my first question....hope this helps you to edit ur macro which u shared...and the result will be in same excel and also...the number of rows in column A can change as per file...Thank you

Comment: See my edits about: I think it gets you more or less there.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur new code.....i modified a bit and i am getting the required result...you made my day :)